# Links inside an open and close list do not work

Tags: html, css

I use CSS only to open/close a list. But once the list is open I cannot open a link of any of the `<li>` items. Why not?

```css
.stufflisted {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.stufflisted:focus+.openlinksstuff {
  display: block;
}

.stufflisted:focus {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.stufflisted {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <button class="stufflisted focus:outline-none">Open my stuffs">
    btn
  </button>
  <ul class="openlinksstuff">
    <li>
      <a href="/site1">site1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/site2">site2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

So why here the `<a>` `hrefs` links do not work and how to make them work? I do not want Javascript for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in CSS by (ab)using the [checkbox hack](https://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/):

```css
#toggle {
  position: relative;
  left: -100vw;
}

#click-to-toggle {
  border: 2px solid #111111;
  background: #111111;
  color: #F5F5F7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

#click-to-toggle:hover {
  background: #F5F5F7;
  color: #111111;
}

.toggled {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .toggled {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle" id="click-to-toggle">
  Click to toggle list
</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">

<br /><br />

<ul class="toggled">
  <li>
    <a href="/site1">site1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/site2">site2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

the possible way with the button is to create two buttons where one hide and other show the list here is the snippet

```css
  button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: red;
  width: 90px;
  height: 30px;
}
.close:focus ~ .list{
  display: none;
}
.open:focus ~ .list{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  <button class="Open">Open</button>
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <a href="/site1">site1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/site2">site2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if he did he hadn't use a button

Comment: because css have on focus but no blur if you need one button you'll need javascript

Comment: And @Gad your solution does not work if I click away from the button and focus turns off

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur i said the `button` because the button doesn't have `checked ` pseodo class on your solution you used `checkbox` that's toggle is possible but on `button` that can't be happen

Comment: and even if you are complaining I admire what you did but that's not the only way

Comment: @Gad I do appreciate the genius of your solution, all I'm saying is that if you unfocus the `<button>` then the list disappears. It's not common UI behaviour so it will be confusing to some users. But neat solution though, nice work!